# What is the formal definition of Θ(f(n)) without expressing Θ(f(n)) in terms of O(f(n)) or Ω(f(n))?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, definition, function-definition

`Θ` or `Θ(f(n))` is often defined in terms of `O(f(n))` or `Ω(f(n))`. Other answers on this site define `Θ(f(n))` in this way. What is the definition of `Θ(f(n))` without using `O` or `Ω`?

Of course, since it is true that `g(n) = Θ(f(n))` iff `g(n) = O(f(n))` and `g(n) = Ω(f(n))`, the definition of `Θ(f(n))` without using `O` or `Ω` will still mirror the definitions of `O` and `Ω` in some way.

Comment: Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation The formal definition doesn't contain O or Ω

Comment: @jabaa I read that before posting, but I'm not familiar with that notation, and so cannot follow the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `h(n)` is in `Θ(k(n))` if there are positive numbers `p` and `q` such that beyond a some value of `n`, `h(n)` ≤ `p * k(n)` and `h(n)` ≥ `q * k(n)`.